# sql server update from select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Following the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select), I have something like this:

```
update MyTable
set column1 = otherTable.SomeColumn,
    column2 = otherTable.SomeOtherColumn
from MyTable
inner join
(select *some complex query here*) as otherTable
on MyTable.key_field = otherTable.key_field;
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> The column prefix 'otherTable' does
>   not match with a table name or alias
>   name used in the query.

I'm not sure what's wrong. Can't I do such an update from a select query like this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I'm using *blush* sql server 2000.)

EDIT:

here's the actual query

```
update pdx_projects set pr_rpc_slr_amount_year_to_date = summary.SumSLR, pr_rpc_hours_year_to_date = summary.SumHours
    from pdx_projects pr join (
select  pr.pr_pk pr_pk, sum(tc.stc_slr_amount)  SumSLR, sum(tc.stc_worked_hours)  SumHours from pdx_time_and_cost_from_rpc tc 
    join pdx_rpc_projects sp on tc.stc_rpc_project_id = sp.sol_rpc_number
    join pdx_rpc_links sl on sl.sol_fk = sp.sol_pk
    join pdx_projects pr on pr_pk = sl.pr_fk
    where tc.stc_time_card_year = year(getdate())
    group by pr_pk
) as summary

on pr.pr_pk = summary.pr_pk
```

and the actual error message is

> Server: Msg 107, Level 16, State 2,
>   Line 1 The column prefix 'summary'
>   does not match with a table name or
>   alias name used in the query.

Comment: Are you sure otherTable.key_field is valid?  We can't say without seeing the *some complex query here*.

Comment: @Fosco The select query has all the referenced fields and runs fine by itself.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy your posted query also has a period at the end.... is that there in what you're running?... You have to give us the real query or we cannot see what's wrong.   The concept/syntax is correct, but you're missing something and need more eyes on it.

Comment: Take a careful look at all of your references to `otherTable` in the query? Are they all spelled correctly?

Comment: @Fosco I have included the actual query I have. @Joe I think I have every thing spelled correctly.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy so the error for the real query is that the column prefix 'summary' does not match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submit to you this altered query:

```
update x
set x.pr_rpc_slr_amount_year_to_date = summary.sumSLR, 
    x.pr_rpc_hours_year_to_date = summary.sumHours
from pdx_projects x
join (
    select  pr.pr_pk as pr_pk, 
            sum(tc.stc_slr_amount) as SumSLR, 
            sum(tc.stc_worked_hours) as SumHours 
    from pdx_time_and_cost_from_rpc tc 
    join pdx_rpc_projects sp on tc.stc_rpc_project_id = sp.sol_rpc_number
    join pdx_rpc_links sl on sp.sol_pk = sl.sol_fk
    join pdx_projects pr on sl.pr_fk = pr.pr_pk
    where tc.stc_time_card_year = year(getdate())
    group by pr.pr_pk
) as summary
on x.pr_pk = summary.pr_pk
```

Notably different here:  I don't re-use the alias `pr` inside and outside of the complex query.  I re-ordered the joins the way I like them (previously referenced table first,) and explicitly notated pr_pk in 2 places.  I also changed the update syntax to use `update <alias>`.

Comment: actually they are not 0. I was just trying something silly but I forgot to revert back. I updated the query immediatly. would those be `summer.SumSLR` instead of 0, in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but instead of generating hugely complex queries, I usually default to inserting the *some complex query here* into a table variable.  Then you can do a simple update to MyTable with a join to the table variable.  It may not be quite as efficient, but its much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your error using SQL 2008 in 80 compatibility level. While this option doesn't guarantee that I'll get the same results as you, nothing appears to be out of place.

```
create table pdx_projects
(
    pr_rpc_slr_amount_year_to_date varchar(max)
    , pr_rpc_hours_year_to_date varchar(max)
    , pr_pk varchar(max)

)

create table pdx_time_and_cost_from_rpc
(
    stc_slr_amount decimal
    , stc_worked_hours decimal
    , stc_rpc_project_id varchar(max)
    , stc_time_card_year varchar(max)
)

create table  pdx_rpc_projects
(
    sol_rpc_number varchar(max)
    , sol_pk varchar(max)
)

create table pdx_rpc_links
(
    sol_fk varchar(max)
    , pr_fk varchar(max)
)


update pdx_projects
set
    pr_rpc_slr_amount_year_to_date = summary.SumSLR
    , pr_rpc_hours_year_to_date = summary.SumHours
from
    pdx_projects pr
join (
    select  pr.pr_pk pr_pk
        , sum(tc.stc_slr_amount)  SumSLR
        , sum(tc.stc_worked_hours)  SumHours
    from pdx_time_and_cost_from_rpc tc 
    join pdx_rpc_projects sp on tc.stc_rpc_project_id = sp.sol_rpc_number
    join pdx_rpc_links sl on sl.sol_fk = sp.sol_pk
    join pdx_projects pr on pr_pk = sl.pr_fk
    where tc.stc_time_card_year = year(getdate())
    group by pr_pk
    ) as summary
    on pr.pr_pk = summary.pr_pk
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I think I was just mis-using alias. See @Fosco's answer that fixed the issue for me. Appreciate the effort though.